# How to write to different hbase tables in apache flume

Tags: apache, mongodb, hbase, flume

I have configured `Apache Flume` to receive messages (`JSON` type) in `HTTP` source. My sinks are `MongoDB` and `HBase`.

How can I write the message according to a specified field to different collections and tables?

For example: let's assume we have `T_1` and `T_2`. Now there is an incoming message that should be saved in `T_1`. How can I handle those messages and assign them where to be saved?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`Multiplexing Channel Selector`](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#multiplexing-channel-selector). The default one ([`Replicating Channel Selector`](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#replicating-channel-selector-default) copies the Flume event produced by the source to all its configured channels. Nevertheless, the multiplexing one is able to put the event into a specific channel depending on the value of a header within the Flume event.

In order to create such a header accordingly to your application logic you will need to create a custom handler for the HTTPSource. This can be easily done by implementing the [`HttpSourceHandler`](http://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/flume/source/http/HTTPSourceHandler.html) interface of the API.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex for tagging message type + multiplexing for sending it to right destination. 
example , based on message "TEST"

regex for a string / field

```
agent.sources.s1.interceptors.i1.type=regex_extractor
agent.sources.s1.interceptors.i1.regex=(TEST1)
```

assign interceptor to serializer SE1

```
agent.sources.s1.interceptors.i1.serializers=SE1
agent.sources.s1.intercetpros.i1.serializers.SE1.name=Test
```

send to required channel , channels (c1,c2) you can map to different sinks

```
agent.sources.s1.selector.type=multiplexing
agent.sources.s1.selector.header=Test
agent.sources.s1.selector.mapping.Test=c1
```

all events of test regex will go to channel c1 , others will be defaulted to C2

```
agent.sources.s1.selector.default=c2
```